# How can I adjust internet settings such as TTL, Rwin, and Max Connections?

Tags: networking, wireless

Is it possible to adjust settings such as TTL, Rwin, and Max Connections on Ubuntu? I am having connectivity issues on Ubuntu with my wireless card. I experience the same issue on Windows XP, at least until I change those settings using TCP Optimizer. I figure if it works for Windows, it may work for Ubuntu as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IPV4 settings are accessible through proc filesystem at /proc/sys/net/ipv4

Example: to read the current TTL value:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
```

To set a new TTL:

```
sudo su
echo 255 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
```

After you decide which settings you want you may wrap the commands in a simple bash script and add it to /etc/rc.local

There may be some GUI programs to do that, but real men don't need them, huh?

Comment: Thanks Sergey! I'm going to give this a shot. Adding it to rc.local will make it run at start-up right? I'm still a little rough with my Ubuntu knowledge.

Comment: Also, in `/etc/rc.local` you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: Why my pings still report a ttl value of 64? I need to set a greater ttl too, but even after issuing that command my pings are still 64.